# How to use oldstandard package properly?

Tags: fonts, symbols, unicode

I have just downloaded the `OldStandard.sty package` avaible on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/oldstandard). Reading the [user's manual](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/fonts/oldstandard/doc/oldstand-manual.pdf) it seems the font should be ready for the `math mode` too. However, in the `mwe` below you can see the equations are typeseted in `Latin Modern`. Is it possible to change this? I had thought about using `mathspec.sty` package but I think it will be better if we can avoid it. Does `OldStandard.sty package` include current symbols as the ones provided by `\in, subset\{\cup` etc?

Another thing I would like to ask you for is about the `italic` 'f'. The `Old Standard font` has loads of files in [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/oldstandard). In particular, the `.tfm` file `OldStandard-Italic-sup-ly` has an alternative 'f' (character number 131). How can I use it instead of the normal ins such a way the `ligatures` are preserved?

Thanks

`MWE`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fonttable}
\usepackage{OldStandard}

\newcommand{\abc}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz }
\newcommand{\ligs}{ff fi fff ffi fl ffl}

\begin{document}
\centering

\fonttable{OldStandard-Italic-sup-ly1.tfm}

\newpage

\abc \ligs

\textit{\abc \ligs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see no statement about math support in the manual. The OpenType font has several math symbols, but it is not tailored for `unicode-math` as is. Certainly there's no math support for the `pdflatex` version.

Comment: LY1 encoding is a legacy 8bit encoding that should never be used with luatex or xetex, character 131 is `\textflorin`  so a currency symbol not a long f for normal text.

Comment: By the way, the package is `OldStandard.sty`. Using lowercase works on Windows, but not on other systems.

Comment: @egreg The guide talks about mathematical operators and mathematical Greek fonts. That is why I thought it could be used in math mode too. And I'll edit the question to capitalise the letters. Thanks for the point.

Comment: @DavidCharlisle Then, there's no say to get that alternative "f"? Maybe using the combofont package or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

The question is very unclear but the legacy pdftex LY1 encoding has \textflorin in position 131.  The florin character is ƒ Unicode U+0192 so as far as I can tell, you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{OldStandard-Regular}
\begin{document}

efgƒ

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not exactly. What I want is to substitute the italic f by the \textflorin (I didn't know it was a currency symbol) but keeping ligatures with this new symbol.

Comment: @Dog Ligatures have to be drawn by the font designer not something that can sensibly be added by tex.  How could you use a font  with all upright letters except f?  Do you want to use the oldstandard italic as your base font?

Comment: No, the main font should be Old Standard regular, but when italic is used, character 131 should replace the usual f. I know ligatures must be provided by the font author so, I'm afraid if such a substitution is done, ligatures won't be possible, due to the character of the 131th glyph.

Comment: it isn't the 131st glyph (that is just a subset numbering for the non standard LY1 encoding for the Y&Y TeX system (which has not been available for years)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks for the remark.